# What is "void before / after the string"?

Tags: c++, regex, string

> There is only one "character" position in an empty string: the void after the string. The first token in the regex is ^. It matches the position before the void after the string, because it is preceded by the void before the string.

This is from [www.regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html)

What is "void before the string" and "void after the string". I have not been able to find this terminology in any of the other places on the Net.

Comment: I don't think "void" is a standard terminology for reqex. Maybe it is described somewhere else in the website?  
Best guess is they just mean the beginning and end, which are "special" for regex.
There are no special characters in a string to mark the beginning or the end. Even a null byte at the end isn't absolutely universal.

Comment: they try to explain that for empty strings, `start` and `end` positions are equal so `^$` matches empty string.

Comment: The article uses "void" as a synonym for "nothing".

Comment: The "one position in an empty string" is not unlike the C++ pointer after an array, or the end iterators. But yes, this is unusual terminology for a common concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That section of www.regular-expressions.info refers to the concepts "void before the string" and "void after the string" in order to help explain exactly what it is that ^ and $ are matching. The ^ and $ each match a *position* in the string, and it's possible that they match *the same position*. In the context of the text you quoted from the site, it is describing a situation where the input string is an empty string. The fact that ^ and $ each match a position (which can be the same position) explains why the regex

```
^$
```

matches an empty string. This wouldn't make sense if one's understanding of ^ and $ was that they referred to two separate things - the "beginning" and the "end". So, the website explains the ^ as matching the *position after the "void before the string"* and the $ as the *position before the "void after the string"*. So it's merely another way of thinking about ^ and $, and why it is that ^$ matches an empty string.